# Toggles class function only works on first element

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

Hi guys I have written the following code in order to be able to toggle a class on and off an element on click.

The element:

`<h4 class="swatch-label-size swatch__label--error">test</h4>`

The functionality:

```
function newFunctionTest() {
    var termsToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch-label-size');

    for (var i = 0; i < termsToggles.length; i++) {
        termsToggles[i].addEventListener('click', toggleTerms);
    }
}

function toggleTerms() {
    var termsSection = document.querySelector('.swatch-label-size');
    termsSection.classList.toggle('js-swatch-open');
}
```

I have three instances on the element with ".swatch-label-size" class in my DOM, but the function only works when I click the first one. Nothing happens on click of the second or third element. Have I not not bound my function to all instances of the class properly?

Comment: You're re-selecting the element inside your `toggleTerms`, not using the element that the click handler was bound to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are again getting the element inside the listener function `toggleTerms` so remove that and it works. Just click the text in the snippet below to get the effect of class being toggled. For simplicity, I have toggled the class that change the font color:

```js
function newFunctionTest() {
  var termsToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch-label-size');
  for (var i = 0; i < termsToggles.length; i++) {
      termsToggles[i].addEventListener('click', toggleTerms);
  }
}

function toggleTerms() {
  this.classList.toggle('js-swatch-open');
} 
//initialize listener
newFunctionTest();
```

```css
.js-swatch-open{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="swatch-label-size swatch__label--error">test1</h4>
<h4 class="swatch-label-size swatch__label--error">test2</h4>
<h4 class="swatch-label-size swatch__label--error">test3</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

The termsSection in toggleTerms would always be the first matched element, you may consider to change it into this

```
function toggleTerms(event) {
    var termsSection = event.target;
    termsSection.classList.toggle('js-swatch-open');
  }
```